Optimize performance of function that creates buffer around non-zero values in numpy array
I have a function that takes a 2 dimensional array, and returns an array of same shape that has a 1 if the value in the original array is next to (horizontally, vertically, or diagonally) a non-zero number, and 0 otherwise.
For example, if you have the following input array:
array([[10,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  2,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])

The output would be
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]])

The way I'm currently doing it is to create a copy of the array, shifting in each direction, and then taking the maximum for each index across all the copies.
This is fine for a tiny array, but I need to run this on very large arrays and it takes a long time. I'm looking for help to significantly reduce execution time on large arrays. I have a feeling there's an efficient way to do this with numpy but can't figure it out. Here's the code I came up with:
def shift_array(arr, direction):
    direction_map = {'left':'-x','right':'+x','up':'+y','down':'-y'}
    if direction not in direction_map.keys():
        raise ValueError(f'{direction} is not in {list(direction_map.keys())}')
    direction_val = direction_map[direction]
    direction_xy = direction_val[1]
    direction_sign = direction_val[0]
    
    if direction_xy == 'x':
        if direction_sign == '-':
            return [[val for val in arr[i][1:]]+[0] for i in range(arr.shape[0])]
        elif direction_sign == '+':
            return [[0]+[val for val in arr[i][:-1]] for i in range(arr.shape[0])]
    elif direction_xy == 'y':
        if direction_sign == '+':
            return [list(val) for val in arr[1:]]+[[0 for _ in arr[0]]]
        elif direction_sign == '-':
            return [[0 for _ in arr[0]]]+[list(val) for val in arr[:-1]]
    

def apply_shifts(input_array):
    arr = input_array.copy()
    arr = np.where(arr>0, 1, 0)
    arrays = [arr]
    directions = ['left','right','up','down', ['left','down'], ['right','down'],['left','up'],['right','up']]
    for direction in directions:
        if isinstance(direction, str):
            arrays.append(shift_array(arr, direction))
        else:
            tmp_arr = shift_array(arr, direction[0])
            arrays.append(shift_array(tmp_arr, direction[1]))
            
    shape = (len(arrays), len(arrays[0]), len(arrays[0][0]))
    max_array = np.array([np.max([arrays[i][j][k] for i in range(shape[0])]) for j in range(shape[1]) for k in range(shape[2])])
    
    return max_array.reshape(arr.shape)

# example array
import numpy as np
arr1=np.array([[10,0,0,0,0],[0,0,2,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]])
res=apply_shifts(arr1)

I appreciate any help and I'm happy to provide more detail if I'm missing something.

IIUC you want to do convolution with "all-ones" kernel:
from scipy.ndimage import convolve

arr = np.array([[10, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
kernel = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]])

out = convolve(arr, kernel).astype(bool).astype(int)
print(out)

Prints:
[[1 1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 1 0]
 [0 1 1 1 0]]


That looks like it's exactly what I need, much faster than my version. Thanks!
